# How to run script at startup on Pi OS Lite?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I googled before asking here , but I do not want to crash or brake system. So I am interested in how to add command / script / code at startup , I am using RPi 3 B+, with Pi OS Lite.
For example

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I want to run this every time I power on rpi 3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`rc.local`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md)

Comment: write this code in `rc.local` or create `startup.sh` and then write full path of `this.sh` file ?